# PHP Vars From Included Bootstrap Not Showing Up in View

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have created my own little PHP framework for fun, however, I am having trouble passing variables from bootstrap to the views....

if I put an echo,print_r,var_dump my target variable in the bootstrap, the output is displayed in the browser before the  tag... yet the target var in bootstrap.php is not available in the view, it is coming up as "" even though at the top of the page it is being output correctly....

Somethings I noticed from similar questions:

```
- The target variable is not being over written
- The include target path is correct and the file exists
- The file is only being included one time (include_once is only fired once)
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, I am pulling my hair out over here lol...

```
Source Code
```

https://gist.github.com/jeffreyroberts/f330ad4a164adda221aa

Comment: Can you show us some example code ?

Comment: Hey Alban, you can find example code at https://gist.github.com/jeffreyroberts/f330ad4a164adda221aa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display your site name, I think you can use a constant like that :

```
define('SITE_NAME', "Jeff's Site");
```

And then display it in your index.tpl :

```
<?php echo SITE_NAME; ?>
```

---

Or, you can send your variables to the view by extending a little bit your `JLR_Core_Views` :

```
class JLR_Core_Views
{
    private $data;

    public function loadView($templatePath, $data = array())
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $templatePath = JLR_ROOT . '/webroot/' . $templateName . '.tpl';
        if(file_exists($templatePath)) {
            // Yes, I know about the vuln here, this is just an example;
            ob_start();
            include_once $templatePath;
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }

    function __get($name)
    {
        return (isset($this->data[$name]))
            ? $this->data[$name]
            : null;
    }
}
```

Then, you can call your template like that :

```
$view = new JLR_Core_Views();
$view->loadView("index", array("sitename" => "Jeff's Site"));
```

And here is your index.tpl :

```
<?php echo $this->siteName; ?>
```

---

Below is another example of what you can do.

First, you create this class in order to store all the variables you want :

```
<?php
class JLR_Repository {

    private static $data = array();

    public function set($name, $value) {
        self::$data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function get($name) {
        return (isset(self::$data[$name]))
            ? self::$data[$name]
            : null;
    }
}
?>
```

Then, when you want to store something in it :

```
JLR_Repository::set("sitename", "Jeff's Site");
```

And in your index.tpl :

```
<?php echo JLR_Repository::get("sitename"); ?>
```

Comment: The constant works for regular vars, but not for arrays, the example I gave is an extremely simplified version of what I am trying to do, im not in a position to pass variables to the load view method, great looking code though! =]

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Then, you can perhaps use a registry. Many frameworks use it, I'll edit my code to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

try using the 'global' keyword - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: global is a no go, I repeat, thats a negative ghost rider